# Alternative to using return statement

Tags: java

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly the return statement does. What would be the difference in using:

```
public void run()
{
    System.out.println(cube(5));
}

public int cube(int num)
{
    int result = num*num*num;
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

vs

```
public void run()
{
    System.out.println(cube(5));
}

public int cube(int num)
{
   return num*num*num;
}
```

Isn't it basically doing the same?

Comment: The difference is that the first one doesn't compile (because you declared `square` as returning an `int`, but didn't return anything), whereas the second one does.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, the `square` function will print the cube of the provided number. However, if you wanted to do something more with it, like `System.out.println(square(5) + 3)`, printing would not give you back 125 (did you mean to call it cube?) to add to the 3, it would only say "125" in the console. The `return` statement actually makes the function give back 125, so you can continue to work with it as a value.

Additionally, since you declared the `square` function as returning an `int`, if you do not have a `return` statement, then the program will fail to compile.

Answer (score 1):

The return statement allows for more modular code with clear separation of concerns.

In your first example, your first `System.out.println` in the `run()` method calls another method that both calculates and then prints; therefore, the first `System.out.println` doesn't print anything itself, and could be simplified to just

```
public void run() {
    square(5);
}

public void square(int num) {
    System.out.println(num * num);
}
```

Which is nice and concise, but let's say you don't want to `System.out.println` every time you calculate a square, but only print if the result is divisible by 3. If you add the logic for that scenario to your `square()` method, it starts to exceed its responsibility. Additionally, your `square()` method is now only useful to that specific scenario. So the better practice would be something like this:

```
public void run() {
    int result = square(5);

    if (result % 3 == 0) { 
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}   

public int square(int num) {
    return num * num;
}
```

Which now allows you to re-use the `square()` method for other scenarios, rather than just printing squares divisible by 3.

*Unrelated to the code itself, but your `square()` method is actually calculating a cube (num*num*num) rather than a square (num*num)*

Answer (score 0):

The difference would be whether or not you want to do something with the product of the function. If you just want to print the result, you're good to go. If you want to store that value into a variable to use later, you'd want to return it, and you could then call a System.out.println on that variable too. I would say fin nailed it in his response. Hope this helped!